# Delete key in Translations Editor

Tags: android, android-studio, translation

How to delete key in Translations Editor (Android Studio)?
I see only green button "+" to for add new key and button as "earth" for add new language. Bt what if I wanted to delete the created key? How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You must remove string resource with your key from *strings.xml* file

Comment: For each locale?  I deleted the string from the English`strings.xml`, but it still appears in the others.

Comment: It is sufficient to right-click on the key and choose `delete`

Answer (score 4):

You must select the key and push the button (remove key)...

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT0AW.jpg)

Comment: This helps me, see image

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is new in Android Studio 3.2, but you can right click the key and delete it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. *Analyze* > *Run inspection by name* > *Unused resources*.
2. Then you'll see on the bottom all unused resources including *strings*. Right click on specific string resource and choose *Remove Declarations for R.string.test*. It removes all translations for given key.

[image]

PS. Yes, looks like a workaround. But "minus" in Translations Editor doesn't work for me and remove all translations one by one manually - it`s crazy.